# How to get the record name defined in avro schema with python?

Tags: c#, python, avro

I am serializing data with Avro in C#.
Then i deserialize it with Python. Let's assume i have following schema:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "ClassXY",
  "fields" : [{"name": "x", "type": "double"}]
}
```

How can i check on python-side if my record is of type "ClassXY"?
Can i get access to the value(ClassXY) of "name" somehow?

Comment: Do you want to check if dict["type"] == "ClassXY" or do you need to check if some class name is "ClassXY" ? It is unclear for me.

Comment: I want to check if dict['name'] == "ClassXY".

Answer (score 0):

```
message_buf = io.BytesIO(message)
reader = avro.datafile.DataFileReader(message_buf, avro.io.DatumReader())
schema_name = reader.datum_reader.reader_schema.name
```